# EventHub Reciever RecieveTime issue with Null Message

Tags: amqp, iot, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am using `AzureSBLite` wrapper to poll the message from one `eventhub` with specific partition. Eventdata will be sent to one Event hub and Stream analytics will read from there. After processing Stream analytics will write it to different event hub in certain partition.

```
SenderEventHub[Partition-1]-->Stream Analytics -->ReciverEventHub[Partition-2]
```

Receiving part is normally taking `60-150s` on receive method which should not be the case here. I am not sure what is going under wrapper and where its taking. I have verified the output of `streamanalytics` , its almost near instant but receiver is getting nothing.

---

**RecieverCode**

---

```
ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(Helper.ConnectionString);

                    builder.TransportType = TransportType.Amqp;

                    MessagingFactory MessagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(Helper.ConnectionString);

                    EventHubClient client = MessagingFactory.CreateEventHubClient(eventHubEntity as string);

                    EventHubConsumerGroup group = client.GetConsumerGroup(Helper.ConsumerGroup);

                    EventHubReceiver receiver = group.CreateReceiver(Helper.PartitionReciever); 

                    do
                    {
                        EventData data = receiver.Receive();

                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(Helper.Currentoffset = data.Offset);

                            var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventBody>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.GetBytes()));

                            if (msg != null) Helper.Speak(msg.CommandName);
                        }
                    } while (true);
```

[image]

Trying with Same EventHub but two different partition is worse.

---

[image]

*Note:Azure.SeriveBus is not supported on Windows 10 IoT Core.so can't use the EventProcessorHost.*